# 'linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230))' Http Requests every day

Tags: css, http, http-get

I get a ton of these requests below, 400 today which throw 404 errors. Where and why are these being called to my site?  The user agent looks legit.

```
System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230))' was not found on controller 'Tournaments.Controllers.EventController'.
```

**Url**

```
https://basketball.exposureevents.com/128833/third-annual-its-lit-basketball-tournament/linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230))
```

Comment: can you post your live site here?

Comment: I updated the URL with the full one

Comment: Have you searched your application source code for instances of "linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230))"? Perhaps theres some broken code causing the issue. Failing that, is there no referrer info in the request header?

Comment: can you include your route configure for current url?

Comment: There is nothing that matches in the entire code base with that. We are linear-gradient but not in those colors.  Not sure what you mean by include your route configure but the legit URL is https://basketball.exposureevents.com/128833/third-annual-its-lit-basketball-tournament

Comment: Been getting the same thing for years. Some userAgents who are doing this are `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Squidbot/1.0)` and `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; EchoboxBot/1.0; hash/w4mwnpbXf3MFAbxOkJRw; +http://www.echobox.com)`. Quite often the referer is the same url without the linear-gradient crap. The linear-gradient values vary between a few different variants. But none of them exist in my codebase or in the referer page HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just aborted the requests.

```
<rule name="LinearGradientRequest" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*linear-gradient.*$" />
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been receiving similar requests to my site on a daily basis for a long time.

The requests contain a uriEncoded linear-gradient. The referer is the same URL minus the gradient crap. The userAgent indicates it's done primarily by two crawlers: Squidbot and Echobox.

We couldn't find any exact matches for the linear-gradient in our code. We use hsla format for our colors and the requests contained rgba colors!
But then I realized: yep, we did have the exact same gradient in our code, just in a different format.

The origin was a CSS file where this gradient was used as a background-image

`background-image: linear-gradient(...`

What *assume* is going on: These crawlers are trying to crawl all images on a site by making requests to any `background-image` values they find.

And they interpret all css in their preferred color format (rgb based instead of hsl) so that's why there's often no direct match for the exact code.